# Firebase returns nulls for my list of ids

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Until now, Firebase delivered my resource as expected, suddenly it returns a list of nulls and "true" values.

Has anybody experienced this behavior?

I am using C# and the Firesharp library.
There my request looks like this:

```
await Client.GetAsync("runningEvents/crawledIds");
```

The http request in Fiddler looks like this:

```
GET https://sportsevents-56d89.firebaseio.com/runningEvents/crawledIds.json?auth=XXX
```

You can have a look at the data under this link: https://sportsevents-56d89.firebaseio.com/runningEvents/crawledIds.json

So the request seems correct to me.

That is how my data looks like in Firebase (hasn't changed since it worked, only kept adding ids):
[image: My data in Firebase]

That is what the response looks like. Further down the list there are also "true" values. What I need though are the id numbers obviously
[image: That is what the response looks like. Further down the list there are also "true" values. What I need though are the id numbers obviously]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which, I don't know why, kinda sort of works.

By inserting a value like this..

[image: Insert a value]

The response becomes valid again (I have to filter out all non-numeric values now though, which sucks if it wouldn't be just me consuming the data)

The question remains though: Does this make sens to anybody.
Also another question: Why silently downvote this question ?!

[image: Working data again]